# Error return from Google AdWords API

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to upgrade my Google AdWords API process to the latest version (from v201506 to v201603), and I'm getting an error from Google:

```
Invalid ReportDefinition Xml: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'includeZeroImpressions'. No child element is expected at this point
```

My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reportDefinition>
    <selector>
        <fields>AccountDescriptiveName</fields>
        <fields>Date</fields>
        <fields>CampaignName</fields>
        <fields>AdGroupName</fields>
        <fields>Clicks</fields>
        <fields>CampaignId</fields>
        <fields>AdGroupId</fields>
    </selector>
    <reportName>AdWord-Performance-Report-#570e9612587f9</reportName>
    <reportType>ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT</reportType>
    <dateRangeType>TODAY</dateRangeType>
    <downloadFormat>TSV</downloadFormat>
    <includeZeroImpressions>true</includeZeroImpressions>
</reportDefinition>
```

I couldn't find any references in the Google AdWords api blogs referring to changes in includeZeroImpressions... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Damn.. nevermind. I see it in the Migration guide now:

The includeZeroImpressions field in ReportDefinition is removed. Use the HTTP header to include zero impressions in your report results instead.